# Mongoose synchronousFind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, synchronous, node-deasync

I am trying to build a synchronous mongoose find. I adopted the use of deasync.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync

This is currently working for saves but it is not working for queries

```
exports.synchronousFind = function (instanceModel, query) {
    var ready = false;
    var result = null;
    instanceModel.find(query, function (err, tenantUser) {
        ready = true;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            result = tenantUser;
        }
    });

    while (ready === false) {
        require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This part of the code

```
while (ready === false) {
    require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
}
```

Just hangs forever and eventually it goes through. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: While loop is like too fast, by the time it reaches there, it would go through a million loops, So basically you are blocking the entire process by a while loop, which is very very wrong.

Comment: That's what I figured. before using deasync I had a crazy loop that basically blocked everything. The framework is supposed to overcome that

Comment: I changed my code to this just now and it appears to be working     require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return !ready;});

Comment: going to test a few more times before making it the answer

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this and it is now working properly as expected

```
exports.synchronousFind = function (instanceModel, query) {
    var ready = false;
    var result = null;
    instanceModel.find(query, function (err, tenantUser) {
        ready = true;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            result = tenantUser;
        }
    });

    require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return !ready;});

    /*while (ready === false) {
        require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
    }*/
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code: Write the while loop in this way

```
while (!ready) {
    require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
}
```

This will work properly.